# async call on override functions

Tags: c++

if i use the virtual function (*1) in the base class - the following code works as i inspected (print a_tmp and print b_tmp) but not if i use override function's (*2) (2x "print base" will be shown). What is the correct way to call the functions (async) in case of override functions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

class base
{
public:
     virtual void print() = 0;                                       // *1
    // void print() { std::cout << "print base" << std::endl; };     // *2
};
class a_tmp : public base
{
public:
    void print() { std::cout << "print a_tmp" << std::endl; };
};
class b_tmp : public base
{
public:
    void print() { std::cout << "print b_tmp" << std::endl; }
};
std::vector<std::future<void>> future_result;

int main()
{
    a_tmp a_1_tmp;
    b_tmp b_2_tmp;

    base* ab_array[] = { &a_1_tmp,&b_2_tmp };

    for (auto ptr : ab_array)
    {
        future_result.push_back(async(std::launch::async, &base::print ,ptr));

    }
    for (auto& e : future_result) {
        e.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: A virtual function is the correct solution, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks, It is only a example (try out) and for me was the question what is in case of override function's - the way (if exist/possible) to call with future and async.

Comment: Without a virtual base class you aren't declaring overrides you're just declaring new methods with the same name as those in the parent class